# How to hide a modal dialog without returning from .ShowDialog?

Tags: .net, winforms, modal-dialog

I have an application in vb.net that starts with a sub function do some things and decide if it shows itself or not. When it shows itself it does so by invoking `dialog.ShowDialog()`.

When `dialog.ShowDialog()` returns, the application does some cleaning and ends.

I'd like to find a way to temporarily hide the dialog (send it to the system tray) without returning from the ShowDialog() function. However, as soon as I do a `me.Hide()` in the form's code, the form is effectively hidden, but the ShowDialog() function returns and the process is closed.

I understand this is the expected behavior. So my question is how can I get this effect? That is launch a dialog, that can be hidden, and block until the user really wants to quit the application.

Comment: Isn't minimizing to the tray what you are looking for instead of hiding? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918/whats-the-proper-way-to-minimize-to-tray-a-c-winforms-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make this work, ShowDialog() will always return when the form is hidden.  The trick is to use a regular form and a normal call to Application.Run() but to prevent it from becoming visible immediately.  Paste this code into your form class:

```
Protected Overrides Sub SetVisibleCore(ByVal value As Boolean)
    If Not IsHandleCreated Then
        CreateHandle()
        value = false
    End If
    MyBase.SetVisibleCore(value)
End Sub
```

Beware that your Load event handler won't run until the form actually becomes visible so be sure to do any initialization in the Sub New constructor.

Answer (score 6):

If you hide the dialog, you *will* return from ShowDialog().  Forget about trying to change that, you can't.

You might be able to minimize the dialog.

```
form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Or you can position it off screen.

```
form.Left = -16384;
```

Or you can make it transparent [Modifying opacity of any window from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360758/modifying-opacity-of-any-window-from-c)

Comment: Make sure ShowInTaskbar = true if your going to minimize.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to change the modeled form's Opacity property to 0 to make it fully transparent.

```
private void MyModalForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isShowing = true;
    //Do your thing.
    if(!isShowing) this.Opacity = 0.0;
    else this.Opacity = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: opacity is good idea and it doesn't break ShowDialog behavior

Answer (score 0):

I did this, inside code form:

```
private bool CanAccess()
{
    //your condition to access or not
}

private bool AlreadyCreated = false;
protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
{
    if (value && !AlreadyCreated && !CanAccess())
    {
        base.SetVisibleCore(false);
        this.Close();
        return;
    }

    AlreadyCreated = true;
    base.SetVisibleCore(value);
}
```

It work for Show() and ShowDialog() methods.

Answer (score -2):

you may use a flag.

1. Add a flag to your form : `bool done = false;`
2. set done = true when it is complete (in FormClosed event).
3. check for flag in caller function (is it done ?)

   ```
   bool stilInMyFrm = false;
   MyFrm myFrm = new myFrm();

   try
   {
       stilInMyFrm = true;
       myFrm.ShowDialog();
       while (!myFrm.done)
           Application.DoEvents();
   }
   finally
   {
       stilInMyFrm = false;
       cleanup();
   }
   ```